# Upgrading Google Cloud Composer maintaining the same environment and related resources

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am using Google Cloud Composer 2 on GCP.

I am on Composer version 2.1.11 and Airflow version 2.4.3. I want to upgrade my Composer environment to the (currently latest) `composer-2.3.0-airflow-2.5.1` version.

In the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/upgrade-environments), it's reported:

> When you change the version of Airflow or Cloud Composer used by your environment, your environment upgrades. Upgrading does not change how you connect to the resources in your environment, such as the URL of your environment's bucket, or Airflow web server.

This is something you would expect, otherwise It can potentially break many things. However, the first time I upgraded it (a couple of months ago), my current Composer environment was erased and a new one created, with different URL, different bucket on GS, etc.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried both via terraform and the UI.

I am aware that this functionality is still in *Preview* as reported in the docs. However, if the environment is deleted and recreated I think this feature is not useful at all anymore.

Comment: it depends. if it's a minor upgrade, there should be no changes. did you do a major upgrade the first time you upgraded? what was the previous version and the version you upgraded to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your concern. You can go ahead and proceed with the update. As shown in the mages below, there are no changes when doing a minor upgrade. For upgrading, refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/upgrade-environments#upgrade_your_environment).
[image]
[image]